# How to take specific number of input in python

Tags: python-2.7

How do I take a specific number of input in python. Say, if I only want to insert 5 elements in a list then how can I do that?
I tried to do it but couldn't figure out how.

In the first line I want to take an integer which will be the size of the list.
Second line will consist 5 elements separated by a space like this:

5

1 2 3 4 5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
count = int(raw_input("Number of elements:"))
data = raw_input("Data: ")
result = data.split(sep=" ", maxsplit=count)
if len(result) < count:
    print("Too few elements")
```

You can also wrap `int(input("Number of elements:"))` in try/except to ensure that first input is actually int.

p.s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) is helpful q/a how to loop until correct input.

Comment: Varun tagged python2.7, so it'd be probably better to use `int(raw_input())`

Answer (score 1):

**Input :-**

```
5

1 2 3 4 5
```

---

then, use the below code :

---

```
n = int(input())    # Number of elements

List = list ( map ( int, input().split(" ") ) )
```

---

Takes the space separated input as list of integers. Number of elements count is not necessary here. 
You can get the size of the List by **len(List)** . 
Here **list** is a keyword for generating a List.

Or you may use an alternative :

---

```
n = int(input())    # Number of elements

List = [ int(elem) for elem in input().split(" ")  ]
```

---

If you want it as List of strings, then use :

---

```
List = list( input().split(" ") )
```

or

```
s = input()   # default input is string by using input() function in python 2.7+

List = list( s.split(" ") )
```

Or

```
List = [ elem for elem in input().split(" ")  ]
```

---

Number of elements count is necessary while using a loop for receiving input in a new line ,then

---

```
Let the Input be like :

5

1

2

3

4

5
```

---

The modified code will be:-

---

```
n = int(input())

List = [ ]  #declare an Empty list

for i in range(n):

    elem = int(input())

    List.append ( elem )
```

---

**For Earlier version of python , use raw_input ( ) instead of input ( ), which receives default input as String.**

Comment: Varun tagged python2.7, so it'd be probably better to use `int(raw_input())`